# Autowired object is null in Rest controller when deployed on JBoss EAP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss, resteasy

I am using **Springboot** and **RESTEasy** to create a small webapp, in my Controller class I am doing `@Autowire` for my Dao class. Whenever I deploy the code, the dao reference variable always ends up with `null` value. I have used `@Component` for controller and in mail Application class I have used `@SpringBootApplication` and at my dao class also I have added `@Repository` and `@Service`.

Please give some suggestions where exactly i am doing wrong?

**Note: Works fine if I run it as a standalone Springboot app. But this issue occurs when deploy in JBoss server.**

Code format is displayed below: While debugging, at line , `List<DataDto> dataList = dao.findData();` always dao is `null`, because of which API call fails.

```
@Component
@Path("/")
public class apiController {

    @Autowired
    private ApiDao dao;

    public void setApiDao(ApiDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getData")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<DataDto> getDetails(){
        List<DataDto> dataList = dao.findData();
        return logList;
    }
}
```

Dao class code is as below:

```
@Repository
@Service
public class ApiDao {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiDao.class);

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ApiDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public List<SystemEntity> findData() throws SystemException{

        return entityList;
    }
}
```

And for configuration i have used below code and in pom.xml added required dependencies:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/rest/")
public class JaxrsApplication extends Application {

}
```

Comment: Change `@Component` to `@Repository` and try again

Comment: tried by changing to @Repository. But no luck, still its displaying as null only..

Comment: can you show ApiDao ?

Comment: You are using Spring boot then why do you have a JaxrsApplication that extends the Application. This will on JBoss bootstrap a regular application and not a spring boot application. Remove that class and properly configure Spring Boot to be deployed as a war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

JBoss provides inbuilt support for RESTEasy. So in this case the `apiController` is **initialized twice**:

1. Once by Spring
2. Once by JBoss.

The autowiring happens under the hood in the instance initialized by spring but when a call is triggered to the `apiController` it is handled by the instance initialized by JBoss.

### Solution

Disable JBoss from initializing RESTEasy Controllers. In your spring boot application create a `web.xml` under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` and add the following context parameters:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```